# Load and save data from JSON

Tags: objective-c, json, uitableview

I'm a beginner and I try to load data from a Json. I did it, my program take the data from the Json which is on the internet and showing in table view. However  without internet connection my program crashed. Because table view don’t load data.

how can I do so that it shows the data without the Internet?

This is my code:

```
-(void)retrieveData
{

   NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL]] options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    //set up our cities

    citiesArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    if (tempArray.count>0) {

   NSSortDescriptor  *brandDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES];
    //NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:brandDescriptor];
    NSArray *tempjsonArray = [tempArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[brandDescriptor]];

     dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (NSDictionary *word in tempjsonArray) {
        NSString *firstLetter = [[[word objectForKey:@"Name"] substringToIndex:1] uppercaseString];
        NSMutableArray *letterList = [dict objectForKey:firstLetter];
        if (!letterList) {
            letterList = [NSMutableArray array];
            [dict setObject:letterList forKey:firstLetter];
        }
        [letterList addObject:word];

    }  

    citiesArray = [[[dict allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] mutableCopy];
         }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

eg. the user opens the program .On the first time there is an Internet. loading the data from the Json. and then the Internet is disconnected. how to do so would have the user can view the data until such time is that the Internet does not appear again?

**Thanks very much.**

Comment: There are so many ways to persist json data.Show your effort by trying one of them. You can write them to a file, you can save them to user defaults....!

Comment: can I write them in plist? 
or may be use NSData?

Comment: @FaigHuseynov try to store data in nsuserdefault because this is the easy way to store data

Comment: @DarjiJigar NSUserdefault cant store above 1 mb data